# Bootstrap Popover Content not Reactive Vue2

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I am trying to create a component for a popover using Bootstrap4 in Vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div :id="uid + '_Content'" class="d-none">
            <slot name="content">

            </slot>
        </div>
        <div :class="'call' + uid">
            <slot name="caller">

            </slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    data() {
        return {
            uid: this.genUID()
        }
    }, 
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        _this = this;
        // PopOver Definition
        const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.call' + this.uid), {
            container: 'body',
            title: this.title,
            html: true,
            placement: 'auto',
            sanitize: false,
            customClass: 'noselect',
            content: () => {
                return document.querySelector("#" + _this.uid + "_Content").innerHTML;
            }
        });
    },
    methods: {
        genUID() {
            return "Popover_" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

However, when passing content to `<slot name="content">`  from another component, the data is **not** reactive. Is there any config information that I am missing to make it reactive? Is this even possible with Vue and (regular) Bootstrap (*not* Bootstrap-Vue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're losing reactivity because your `content` option to `bootstrap.Popover` is returning a string of your element's HTML, not the element itself. The popover just copies the HTML as it exists when it is opened. If you pass the element, Bootstrap will reparent the element itself into the popover, so changes to the element's children should be reflected. (Note that this could still be disrupted by a virtual DOM change that rewrote the element itself, which is why Bootstrap-Vue would still be better here.) If the popover might be reused, you'll need to reparent the element back into your component's own tree each time the popover is closed. You'll also need to make provision for the `_Content` element to only be hidden while it isn't reparented.

Here's how it all would look:

```html
<template>
    <div ref="container" class="Popover__Container">
        <div ref="content" class="Popover__Content">
            <slot name="content">

            </slot>
        </div>
        <div ref="caller" class="Popover__Caller">
            <slot name="caller">

            </slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    props: {
        title: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: ''
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        const content = this.$refs.content;
        // PopOver Definition
        const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(this.$refs.caller, {
            container: 'body',
            title: this.title,
            html: true,
            placement: 'auto',
            sanitize: false,
            customClass: 'noselect',
            content: content
        });
        $(this.$refs.caller).on('hidden.bs.popover', () =>
        {
          this.$refs.container.prepend(content);
        });
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.Popover__Container > .Popover__Content {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

(I've also replaced the UID approach with refs, since that is a more Vue-like approach.)

Comment: I was thinking it had something to do with the .innerHTML but I had NO idea how to fix it. Everything you said makes sense AND works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: However, when closing the popup, it is not able to be reopened. Any suggestions? (Error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null").. It looks like it moves the Popover_XXX_Content over but never back.

Comment: Ah, yes, looks like Bootstrap doesn't do that for you. I've edited my answer to reparent the content back into your component when the popover is closed. I've also expanded the code into a full copy of your original, with the UID bits replaced with Vue refs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Just so you are aware, it looks like (when transitioning to refs) the caller.on is not necessary.